# Need optimal tableaus be unique assuming unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

If so, why?

If not, do they differ by some ERO/s? That is, they are row equivalent?

This is the problem (taken from Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198)):

---

[image]

---

My classmate gave an optimal tableau that is different from the one obtained by both the computer and myself:

---

[image]

---

I solved the following ([here](http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/simplex.html)):

$$\text{Maximize }z = 3x_1 + x_2 + 3x_3$$

Subject to:

$$2x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \le 2$$

$$x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 \le 5$$

$$2x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 \le 6$$

---

The computer and I got:

[image]

or

[image]

---

While the tableaus are different, my classmate, the computer, and I have the same optimal solution of

$$z = \frac{27}{5};\text{ }x_1 = \frac{1}{5}, x_2 = 0, x_3 = \frac{8}{5}$$

Is it possible that both tableaus are correct? If so, can one be obtained from the other through EROs? Is there some kind of theorem for this? Optimal tableaus are row equivalent or something like that?

Comment: The solution to a LP is not necessarily unique. For example in a game like, rock-paper-scissors, there are many optimal strategies. (N.B: this analogy is  very relevant, because solutions to linear problems and Nash equilibria for zero-sum games are exactly the same object :)).

Comment: @dohmatob Assuming it is unique

Comment: I don't get your remark. Assuming what is unique ?

Comment: @dohmatob Assuming the solution to the LP is unique, si the optimal tableau unique? Okay so no. Can one optimal tableau be obtained from another optimal tableau through EROs?